# Catching all outgoing http requests in a feature test

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, laravel-10

I have some methods on controllers and jobs that contact external services like Stripe and Mailchimp.

When I write feature tests, this can really slow them down, not to mention adding test data to the accounts they are connected to.

I know I can fake a request if I just rewrite all the code inside the test, but that defeats the purpose of writing a test for the existing code in these methods. Is there a way to make a http request to a controller and catch all the outgoing http requests that any of the Laravel code makes so I can fake it reaching the external service?

For instance, if I have a controller method like this:

```
class ProgramController extends Controller
{
    public function invite(ProgramInviteRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $mailchimp = new ApiClient();
        $mailchimp->setConfig([
            'apiKey' => config('services.mailchimp.api_key'),
            'server' => config('services.mailchimp.server_prefix'),
        ]);

        // Confirm they are on the list before sending the invite.
        $response = $mailchimp->lists->getListMemberTags($request->list_id, md5($request->email));

        $has_tag = collect($response->tags)->contains(function ($tag) {
            return $tag->name == 'Program Member';
        });

        if (!$has_tag) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Not a program member.'], 404);
        }

        InviteToProgram::dispatch($request->email);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Invitation sent.']);
    }
}
```

I'd want to respond to the Mailchimp API request to `getListMemberTags` using fake data in the feature test that I run by doing something like this:

```
$response = $this->post(route('program.invite'), [
    'email'   => fake()->safeEmail,
    'list_id' => 'fake_list_id',
]);
$response->assertStatus(404);
```

However, in the above, the invite method's API call would get proxied to a local response.

Comment: You should mock `ApiClient` or fake it if it has a Facade, so you can return whatever you want (should stick to what `ApiClient` could give back as a response

Answer (score 0):

You could try https://github.com/php-vcr/php-vcr which will record your interactions with the api's and then play them back as a test.
So you get real responses and don't need to rewrite everything as you say.

Comment: It looks like the Mailchimp SDK is using Guzzle behind the scenes. Will this intercept Guzzle calls as well?

Comment: As I understand it should intercept the outgoing http traffic and record the response no matter what libraries are used to get there.

Comment: I think this is way more complex and adds nearly no value, it is a good package, but he can just mock the class and return whatever he wants (of course, something that would make sense in this case). I have never needed to use the package you are sharing, and I never saw someone using it (in Laravel), so I would stick to mocking stuff instead of following the path of that package (at least how it is done in the Laravel way)

Comment: Possibly a fair comment @matiaslauriti . Personally I have never used it, but I have seen it demonstrated at a meetup and the value I saw it provide was being able to quickly get real mock data from the service and use that for replays. 

You are going to call the service somehow to get an example response, so let vcr do it.

Just my 2 cents - your kilometers may vary.